# Union two List in C#

Tags: c#, gridview, rowcommand

I want to union, merge in a List that contains both references, so this is my code, how can I define a list ready for this porpouses?

```
if (e.CommandName == "AddtoSelected")
{
    List<DetalleCita> lstAux = new List<DetalleCita>();
    foreach (GridViewRow row in this.dgvEstudios.Rows)
    {
        var GridData = GetValues(row);
        var GridData2 = GetValues(row);
        IList AftList2 = GridData2.Values.Where(r => r != null).ToList();
        AftList2.Cast<DetalleCita>();
        chkEstudio = dgvEstudios.Rows[index].FindControl("ChkAsignar") as CheckBox;
        if (chkEstudio.Checked)
        {

            IList AftList = GridData.Values.Where(r => r != null).ToList();
            lstAux.Add(
            new DetalleCita
            {
                codigoclase = Convert.ToInt32(AftList[0]),
                nombreestudio = AftList[1].ToString(),
                precioestudio = Convert.ToDouble(AftList[2]),
                horacita = dt,
                codigoestudio = AftList[4].ToString()
            });
        }
        index++;
        //this line to merge
        lstAux.ToList().AddRange(AftList2);
    }

    dgvEstudios.DataSource = lstAux;
    dgvEstudios.DataBind();
}
```

this is inside a rowcommand event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to add all entries from `AftList2` to `lstAux` you should define `AftList2` as IEnumerable<> with elements of type `DetalleCita` (being `IEnumerable<DetalleCita>` is enough to be used as parameter of `AddRange()` on `List<DetalleCita>`). For example like this:

```
var AftList2 = GridData2.Values.Where(r => r != null).Cast<DetalleCita>();
```

And then you can add all its elements to `lstAux`:

```
lstAux.AddRange(AftList2);
```

Clarification:

I think you are misunderstanding what extension method `ToList()` does. It **creates** new list from `IEnumerable<T>` and its result is not connected with original `IEnumerable<T>` that it is applied to.

That is why you are just do nothing useful trying to do `list.ToList().AddRange(...)` - you are copying list to (another newly created by `ToList()`) list, update it and then basically throwing away it (because you are not even doing something like `list2 = var1.ToList()`, original `var1` stays unchanged after that!!! you most likely want to save result of `ToList()` if you are calling it).

Also you don't usually need to convert one list to another list, `ToList()` is useful when you need list (`List<T>`) but have `IEnumerable<T>` (that is not indexable and you may need fast access by index, or lazy evaluates but you need all results calculated at this time -- both situations may arise while trying to use result of LINQ to objects query for example: `IEnumerable<int> ints = from i in anotherInts where i > 20 select i;` -- even if `anotherInts` was `List<int>` result of query `ints` **cannot be cast** to `List<int>` because it is not list but implementation of `IEnumerable<int>`. In this case you could use `ToList()` to get list anyway: `List<int> ints = (from i in anotherInts where i > 20 select i).ToList();`).

UPDATE:

If you really mean union semantics (e.g. for { 1, 2 } and { 1, 3 } *union* would be something like { 1, 2, 3 }, with no duplication of equal elements from two collections) consider switching to `HashSet<T>` (it most likely available in your situation 'cause you are using C# 3.0 and I suppose yoou have recent .NET framework) or use `Union()` extension method instead of `AddRange` (I don't think this is better than first solution and be careful because it works more like `ToList()` --  `a.Union(b)` return new collection and does NOT updates either `a` or `b`).